# Automatically create a copy of gmail emails into a folder/label while leaving original in inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to create a rule in Gmail to automatically make a "COPY" of an incoming e-mail and move that copy to a different label/folder while leaving the original in my main inbox.

That way I can read and delete the original e-mail but have a copy in an appropriate folder without having to look through all of my folders for new messages.

I just read and delete from my main inbox and a copy of important e-mails is automatically already in the proper folder for later use if needed.

Answer (score 3):

No, Gmail only has 1 copy of each email and it is only in one place no matter how many labels it has so if you delete it from one view you are deleting the one and only copy of that email.

[How Gmail stores your email](http://gmail-miscellany.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-gmail-stores-your-mail.html):

> In GMail, to remove a message from the Inbox, you remove the Inbox
>   label - just select or open the message and click the Archive button
>   to do that. Or you can do it manually by opening the message and
>   clicking the "x" next to the Inbox label in the message heading.